# Linearize objective function for intlinprog

Tags: optimization, absolute-value, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming, linearization

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3871276/linearize-absolute-value-constraint) is the predecessor to the following question:

I have some constraints based on which I have written a Matlab program that provides me some feasible binary bits for Finite state machines(FSM). However, there is no objective function.

My objective function should be to minimize the Hamming distance (**HD**) between all of the transitions between the obtained binary bits.

It should be **Minimize** $\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq k}   p_{i,j}\sum_{l=1}^{n} |x_{il} - x_{jl}|$ , $i\neq j $

$\sum_{l=1}^{n} |x_{il} - x_{jl}|$ is the HD between the binary bits that I would like to minimize and then sum all of them, considering each transition. Notations- $n$ binary bits, $p_{i,j}$ is some value I would like to multiply with each of the HD, $k$ state FSM.

How do I linearize this?

Comment: Minimize $|x|$ is the same as minimize $t$ subject to $t\geq x, t\geq -x$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek You should turn this into an answer.

Comment: What is t here? Sorry I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry I am new at this ..please elaborate if possible..How do I linearize this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you have an objective of the form
$$\mathrm{minimize} \sum_i p_i|u_i|$$
where $u_i$ are some variables or linear expressions of other variables, and $p_i$ are nonnegative constants, you can linearize it as
$$\begin{array}{rl}
   \mathrm{minimize}  & \sum_i p_it_i\\
   \mathrm{subject\ to}& t_i\geq u_i, \\
                      & t_i\geq -u_i,
\end{array}$$
where $t_i$ are additional auxiliary variables you introduce.

Comment: I am really sorry. Could you replace $u_i$ as $|x_{il} - x_{jl}|$ and in the corresponding linear form please? I am still confused. Sorry totally new and dumb.